# How to use graphic object in JavaFX TabPane

Tags: javafx

Please see the picture below. I don't known how to use Tab Pane in Java FX in this case, Please tell me "is Java FX can do it?, if yes please tell me how to do it". Thank a lot!
[image: I want to use graphic in Tab Pane like picture below, how to do it?]

Comment: I don't really get what you want to achieve here

Comment: @ItachiUchiha On the right of the picture I want to show "tab's graphic" that I have set it on the left

Comment: Are you Talking about the overflow list?

Comment: @tomsontom please see this picture https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5Hq3ztFfdlCUTN5aURjcXZxTTQ/view?usp=sharing